# Calling C# event from C++

Tags: c#, c++, com, function-pointers

I would like to know what is best practice to call c# code from c++ code? What I want exactly: I have already written c++ code and when user uses this program and come across certain functions in c++ code I want to call another c# code to execute something else, so its like delegation between languages. How could I best accomplish this? My idea so far is: in c# I could make web service and then call it with c++.

Comment: Consider making the C# class a COM object so you can call it directly from C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a solution using `C++\Cli` and `boost::function`

native code:

```
typedef void MemberFunctionPointerType(int x);

class NativeClass
{
public:
    //I used boost but any function pointer will work
    void setDelegate(boost::function<MemberFunctionPointerType> delegate)
        {
            m_delegate = delegate;
        }
    void DoSomeThing()
        {
            int x;
            //do your logic here
            ...
            ...
            ...
            //when the needed event occurs call the callbackfunction so the class which registered to event will get his function called.
            m_delegate(x);                     

private:
    boost::function<MemberFunctionPointerType> m_delegate;        

};
```

managed code:

```
typedef MemberFunctionPointerType* CallbackFunctionType;
delegate void CallbackFuncDelegate;

class ManagedClass
{
public:
    ManagedClass()
    {
        m_delegate = gcnew CallbackFuncDelegate(this,&ManagedClass::CallBackFunction);
        m_native = new NativeClass();

        //register the delegate;
        boost::function<MemberFunctionPointerType> funcPointer(static_cast<CallbackFunctionType>(Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(m_delegate).ToPointer()));
        m_native->setDelegate(funcPointer);
    }
    //the callback function will be called every time the nativeClass event occurs.
    void CallBackFunction()
    {
        //do your logic or call your c# method
    }

private:
    CallbackFuncDelegate^ m_delegate ;
    NativeClass* m_native;    
};
```

So why does this work and the Garbage Collector doesn't ruin everything:
    There are 2 things to worry about when dealing with the GC:

1) Collection of the delegate:
       The delegate wont be collected as long as the ManagedClass is alive. So we don't have to worry about it.

2) Reallocation:
       The GC may reallocate the object in the memory as it will but the native code doesn't get a direct pointer to the delegate but rather a pointer to some chunk of code generated by the marshaler.
      This indirection ensures that the native function pointer remains valid even if the delegate is being moved.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to export C# classes as com visible classes. Then use them in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Unmanaged Exports](https://nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports). I personally use it to call C# functions from native C++ application.